# hover one div in a series of similar, show the other

Tags: javascript, jquery

guys. I have several goods with description. I need "tile-description" appear when I hover over a "middle tile". Besides, I need a border around the "large-tile" on hover. Here is the mark-up and some js that I used, but it didn't work for me. Help me, please!

```js
    $(".middle-tile").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).parent().siblings().css('opacity', 1);
});
 $(".middle-tile").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings().css('opacity', 0);
});
```

```css
.tile-description{
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 10;
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="large-tile">
    <div class="middle-tile">
        <div class="tile-data"> 
           <div class="tile-img"><a href=""><img src="img/item-2.jpg" alt="" ></a></div>
           <div class="tile-title"><a href="">Title</a></div>
        </div>
           <button class="btn price">3 697</button>
     </div>
     <div class="tile-description">
         <p>Some specs</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "tile-description" is "middle-tile"s sibling, or "large-tile"s child. But you are selecting it like it's "large-tile"s sibling, which is wrong

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** instead of `sibling` when you use with `parent` or just **[`sibling`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** without `parent` as below:

```
$(this).parent().find('.tile-description').css('opacity', 1);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jr925cx1/3/)**

Or

```
$(this).siblings('.tile-description').css('opacity', 1);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jr925cx1/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

Just use as CSS rule:

```
.middle-tile:hover + .tile-description {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

### -DEMO (using transition btw)

Comment: Good to see with CSS.. :)